# Why does 目 have a counting sense to it?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Why does 目 get used in situations like 二個目? How did it come about getting the meaning of eye as well as some counting meaning?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's related to the sense mentioned by Brandon, from an underlying idea of "something that sticks out visually", hence the use of 目{め} "eye".  This same sense of "visually notable or prominent feature" gives rise to many other uses of 目{め}, such as 結{むす}び目{め} "knot" from 結{むす}び "tying" + 目{め} "visually prominent feature", or 籠{かご}目{め} "lattice" from 籠{かご} "basket, basket-style weave" + 目{め} "visually prominent feature".  It also attaches to adjectives (though it is generally spelled in kana then), as in 長{なが}め "longish, on the long side".

FWIW, Shogakukan's entry for 目{め} breaks the definitions down a bit differently than Daijisen.  Some of the definitions that are relevant to ideas of counting include (my additions in [square brackets]):

> (3)　見る対象をいう。
>     Indicates the object of seeing/looking.

or:

> (5)　連続する、物と物との隙間（すきま）。間の区切り。区切りをつける線条。また、そのように刻まれたもの。
>     Gap between successive items.  Separation between.  Line separating things.  Or, a notch cut as such a line.

or:

> (6)　空間的、時間的な切れ目。二つの物、あるいは二つの事態の区切りや接点。転じて、物の条理、また計量の区切りや、単位をいう。多くの場合、動詞の連用形と複合して用いられる。「切れ目」「切り目」「分け目」「折り目」「裂け目」「境目」「合わせ目」「繋ぎ目」「綴じ目」「くけ目」など。
>     A spatial or temporal gap / break.  [Note that this definition uses the word being defined...]  The divider or point of contact between two things or situations.  By extension, a division or unit in the reason for or measurement of things.  In most cases, used in combination with the *ren'yōkei* [continuative form, i.e. *-masu* stem] of a verb.  *Kireme* "break/gap", *kirime* "cut", *wakeme* "split", *orime* "bend, fold", *sakeme* "rip, tear", *sakaime* "boundary, border line", *awaseme* "join, seam", *tsunagime* "connection, joint", *tojime* "binding", *kukeme* "stitch", etc.

or:

> Ⅲ　〔接尾〕  (Suffix)
>     1　数詞のあとに付いて、初めから数え進んでひと区切りをつけた、その区切りまでの数を表すのに用いる。「二番目」
>     Attached after a counter [such as 個{こ} or 番{ばん}], used to express the number counted when counting the divisions between items from the start [that is, the ordinal or positional number].  *Nibanme* "second"
>     .
>     2　形容詞の語幹、動詞の連用形などに付いて、そのような度合、加減、性質、傾向の意味を添える。「細め」「長め」「控えめ」「おさえめ」など。現代では、形容詞の連体形に付けていう場合もみられる。「細いめ」「長いめ」など。
>     Attached to forms such as an adjective's stem or the *ren'yōkei* of a verb, adds a sense of that kind of degree, extent, quality, or tendency.  *Hosome* "slender-ish", *nagame* "long-ish", *hikaeme* "moderate, with reserve", *osaeme* "restrained", etc.  In modern Japanese, also seen attached to the *rentaikei* [attributive form, same as the dictionary form] of adjectives.  *Hosoi-me* "slender-ish", *nagai-me* "long-ish", etc.

That's a lot to digest, so:

#### TL;DR:

The word 目{め} is generally translated just as "eye", but idiomatically, it is used to express a wide array of ideas related to the basic sense, "**visually prominent feature**".  This is one of the more productive and useful words in Japanese, and learning the many uses of this term will serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

Wild speculation, but it could be related to [sense 10 in 大辞泉](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%9B%AE):

> 10 線状に1列に並んだものの間にできたすきまや凹凸。「櫛【くし】の―」
>     A gap or unevenness occurring between items arranged in a line.  *kushi no - [**me**]* (the **gaps** between the teeth of a comb)

And from this notion, the notion of first, second, third. Or, maybe it's just 当て字 for some homophonous grammatical suffix. I couldn't track down anything concrete though.

Comment: I'm not sure what that sentence is saying- nor do I see 目 in it, could you translate?

Comment: @Anthony -- I just added a translation, hope that helps.  The bit in 「Japanese-style quotes」 there on the end is an example usage, replacing the headword 目 with the dash ―.  This kind of replacement is extremely common in usage examples provided in Japanese dictionaries.  So the 目 is there, albeit not in an immediately obvious way.