# -ish: め/目 vs. っぽい

Tags: words, nuances

As far as I know, one of `め/目`'s usages is to function as a suffix to express a certain similarity, to say something is `__ish`. However, how is it different from `っぽい`?

According to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18056/why-does-%E7%9B%AE-have-a-counting-sense-to-it), one can attach め to the **連用形 of a verb**, **連体形 of i-adjectives**, and **辞書形 (?) of na-adjectives** according to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/slightly-somewhat-%E3%81%AE-%EF%BD%9E%E7%9B%AE%E3%82%81-usage-and-limitations). Nonetheless, I just read this in a news article: [木目調の建物](https://www.fnn-news.com/news/headlines/articles/CONN00390618.html), which I believe is 目 attached to 木, **a noun**.

In addition, according to [Maggie Sensei](http://maggiesensei.com/2016/04/08/adjective-%E7%9B%AE%EF%BC%8F%E3%82%81-me/), and here I quote:

> It won’t work with all adjectives. You usually use this with
>   adjectives that express the degree, size, amount, etc. Though you are
>   not supposed to use this form with na-adjective, you will see it used
>   this way in conversation sometimes.

If all of the above is true, め/目 seems not to differ at all from っぽい in terms of formation. According to [Japanesetest4you](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84-ppoi/), here's how っぽい is formed:

**Verb-stem + っぽい

Noun + っぽい

いadj (-い) + っぽい

なadj + っぽい**

Apparently, there does not appear to be any difference between め/目 and っぽい in terms of formation. Notwithstanding grammar, I assume each has its own specific words to go with, context/set phrases to be used in, etc.

**Question:**

1. Is there a rule that governs when to prefer one over the other, or is this something only exposure and experience can resolve?
2. め/目 seems rarely used with na-adjectives and nounsーif at all. Could anyone provide some common examples you have come across?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer your first question because the precondition is not correct. Let me explain what it is.

The suffix 目 doesn't mean っぽい but that, as the answer in the link says, something has that tendency. In other words, やすめ means "**relatively** low-cost", while 安っぽい is "cheap".

Second, 目 as in 木目 is not the suffix but a noun that means "pattern" and 木目 is a compound.

An example of a na adjective I often hear is きれいめ, (edit) which means "not too casual (for outfits)".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a good answer for your question but I think that while both have a "-ish" sense they are differen't "ishes"

Compare:

安め means on the cheap side in terms of prices (e.g. [安めの価格](https://www.tripadvisor.jp/ShowUserReviews-g1066457-d1687664-r351172407-Kaitenzushioedo-Shinjuku_Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html)).

But

安っぽい means it seems cheap

So the general use of 目・め is something like "one the X side" where X is whatever came before it.

But ぽい means something seems/appears like it is that thing -- even it is that thing ([see ALC](https://www.alc.co.jp/jpn/article/faq/03/125.html)).

Comment: I find it interesting how 高めの値段 yields hundreds of thousands of results, whereas 高っぽい値段 yields almost none. The ALC article is a bit hard for me, but still a helpful read. I appreciate it.